# Hide/Show Toggles with jQuery not Toggling?

Tags: jquery

I know this is easy to do and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm looking to hide/show 4 different divs using jQuery toggles.

I have a fiddle going here:  http://jsfiddle.net/4SDesignStudio/agjqj80t/

What am I missing?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="wine-filters">
    <li style="float:left; margin-right:1.5em;">Filters:</li>
    <li class="button-row red-filter">Reds</li>
    <li class="button-row white-filter">Whites</li>
    <li class="button-row sparkling-filter">Sparkling</li>
    <li class="button-row dessert-filter">Dessert</li>
</ul>

<div class="red-wine">
     ** A bunch of <article> sections with each red wine **
</div>

<div class="white-wine">
     ** A bunch of <article> sections with each white wine **
</div>

<div class="sparkling-wine">
     ** A bunch of <article> sections with each sparkling wine **
</div>

<div class="dessert-wine">
     ** A bunch of <article> sections with each dessert wine **
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $redFilter = $('red-filter');
var $whiteFilter = $('white-filter');
var $sparklingFilter = $('sparkling-filter');
var $dessertFilter = $('dessert-filter');    
var $redWine = $('.red-wine');
var $whiteWine = $('.white-wine');
var $sparklingWine = $('.sparkling-wine');
var $dessertWine = $('.dessert-wine');


// Event handlers - Wine Filters

$redFilter.on('click', function(event) {
$redWine.toggle('show');
$whiteWine.toggle('hide');
$sparklingWine.toggle('hide');
$dessertWine.toggle('hide');
});

$whiteFilter.on('click', function(event) {
$redWine.toggle('hide');
$whiteWine.toggle('show');
$sparklingWine.toggle('hide');
$dessertWine.toggle('hide');
});

$sparklingFilter.on('click', function(event) {
$redWine.toggle('hide');
$whiteWine.toggle('hide');
$sparklingWine.toggle('show');
$dessertWine.toggle('hide');
});

$dessertFilter.on('click', function(event) {
$redWine.toggle('hide');
$whiteWine.toggle('hide');
$sparklingWine.toggle('hide');
$dessertWine.toggle('show');
 });
```

Comment: Well your first four jQuery selectors are missing the leading period. Ex: `var $redFilter = $('red-filter');` should be `var $redFilter = $('.red-filter');`.

Comment: var $redFilter = $('red-filter'); should read var $redFilter = $('.red-filter');

Comment: Second, `.toggle()` doesn't accept a show/hide string but it does accept a true/false boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agjqj80t/2/)

I think you're using `.toggle()` wrong. Toggle will hide/show the element depending on whether or not is is shown/hidden. Since you already know what you want to accomplish with your toggle, why not do it like this:

```
$redFilter.on('click', function(event) {
  $redWine.show();
  $whiteWine.hide();
  $sparklingWine.hide();
  $dessertWine.hide();
});
```

Since `.toggle('hide');` **shouldn't** (?) work.

Also, as per the comments:

```
var $redFilter = $('.red-filter');
var $whiteFilter = $('.white-filter');
var $sparklingFilter = $('.sparkling-filter');
var $dessertFilter = $('.dessert-filter');
```

Missing the `.` selector for classes on your first 4 variables.

Comment: I thought toggle won't work like this too, but it seems to work.

Comment: @nima Yeah, I checked the documents on `.toggle()` function didn't see them accepting `show` or `hide` as a parameter, but that does seem to work. Very strange.

Comment: I think even though it works, it's not a good idea to use an undocumented feature and the OP should use show/hide as you said.

Comment: @nima I agree, just because something works doesn't mean it should be used :P. But j08691 has a much more elegant solution.

Comment: @TimLewis - Thanks buddy.  The missing "." in the selector was the simple mistake that I'm prone to as I'm learning jQuery.  I had used toggle once before in a different application and got the result I was looking for and just took it for granted.  The simple show/hide makes much more sense.

Comment: @sforcash No problem! Javascript/JQuery is one of those things that takes a lot of practice, trial and error to fully understand. Best of luck :)

Comment: When I'm implementing this into my actual project, I'm getting a console error - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.  
If you've got a spare minute, my working copy is at www.4sdesignstudio.com/new-projects/bwh/livermore-wine-cellar.html

Comment: You're getting an error on line 736 of your `.html` document on this line: `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();` Your document doesn't know what the `.jScrollPane()` function is.

Comment: I was just about to delete that comment realizing it had nothing to do with this.  I'm such a mess =)

Comment: That's ok :P If you're not using it, look into Firefox Developer Version, it's a new browser from Mozilla specifically designed for Web Designers/Developers. That's how I'm debugging a ton of my stuff. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

As I commented above there are two issues:

1. Your first four jQuery selectors are missing the leading period. Ex: `var $redFilter = $('red-filter');` should be `var $redFilter = $('.red-filter');`.
2. `.toggle()` doesn't accept a show/hide string but it does accept a true/false boolean.

However if you just add a data attribute to your list items (e.g.) you could reduce the jQuery to:

```
$('.button-row').click(function () {
    $('ul ~ div').hide();
    $('.' + $(this).data('type')).show()
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ohsLjfxq/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors in these four lines are missing '.'

```
var $redFilter = $('red-filter');
var $whiteFilter = $('white-filter');
var $sparklingFilter = $('sparkling-filter');
var $dessertFilter = $('dessert-filter');
```

Add the period, eg `.red-filter` to fix.